# Como alterar background-color de um botão dentro de um Iframe com Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, css

Boa Tarde pessoal, estou tentando executar um função dentro de um iframe para alterar o background-color de um botão que esta em outro Iframe, comecei a fazer ma já fiz vários teste e não consegui alguém pode me ajudar.

```
//Iframe A
<hmtl>
<head>
<script>
function mudarCorBotao ()
{$(":button").contents("iFrameBotoes").find("btnId").css({"background-color": "yellow"});
</script>
<head>
<body>
codigos...
</body>
</html>
```

Este é o condigo do iframe B

```
<div id="divBotoes"> <iframe id="iFrameBotoes"></iframe></div>
```

Obs: Os dois iframes estão no mesmo html(pai), portanto preciso que iframe A faça alterações no Iframe B, os botões são cirados em uma função c# e inseridos no iframe B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

- Use `$('#iFrameBotoes', parent.document)` para selecionar o documento pai e buscar o iframe B pelo seu `id`;
- Selecione o conteúdo do iframe com `.contents()`;
- Busque o botão pelo seu `id` com `.find("#btnId")`;
- Altere o CSS com `.css({"background-color": "yellow"})`.

A função ficará assim:

```
function mudarCorBotao(){
   $('#iFrameBotoes', parent.document)
   .contents()
   .find("#btnId")
   .css({"background-color": "yellow"});
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!